# Cursor - внутреннее отображение данных

Tags: android, cursor

В каком виде/формате содержатся данные в `Cursor`'е?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данные в классе `Cursor` находятся в формате, который получен из БД  - INTEGER TEXT DATE и тд. , а фактически, видимо, в текстовом, числовом или байтовом виде, как некий набор символов\кодов в зависимости от типа. [Подробнее](http://xbb.uz/db/Tipy-dannyh-v-SQLite-versii-3) о типах SQLite и их представлении.

Извлечь их и преобразовать в Java-типы вы можете с помощью методов класса `Cursor`, например:
`cursor.getInt()` - вернет число целого типа int
`cursor.getFloat()` - вернет вещественное число типа float
`cursor.getString()` - вернет строку

При этом данные, извлекаемые из столбцов БД должны быть сопоставимого типа, то есть вы не можете из поля TEXT (с текстовым содержимым) получить число int и получите исключение, но можете извлечь из поля INTEGER с числом данные в виде строки, которая при этом фактически будет не числом, с которым можно производить арифметические операции, но строкой с текстом в виде чисел.

Comment: Благодаря вашему ответу, о том, что "находятся в формате, который получен из БД" заметил, что неточно видимо сформулировал вопрос, потому отмечу ваш ответ. Но все же, сама структура `Cursor'a` это реальный массив? Точнее, от чего наследует/реализует он свою структуру, в которой хранятся данные как есть полученные из БД?

Comment: Разобраться в этом представляется довольно затруднительно, так как исходный код связанных классов уходит в вызовы нативных процедур, а сам гугл не особо распространяется о внутреннем устройстве этого класса и его данных. Может, если вы скажете зачем именно вам это знать, то получите более удовлетворительный ответ.

Comment: Банальное любопытство.

Answer (score 1):

`Cursor` надо воспринимать как Набор для Бд он содержит в себе все то,что ровно туда положите и потом вы извлекаете оттуда все через CursorAdapter вот некий пример  .

Создание шаблон вида

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBody"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Study cursors"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPriority"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Определение адаптера

```
public class TodoCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
  public TodoCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
      super(context, cursor, 0);
  }

  // The newView method is used to inflate a new view and return it, 
  // you don't bind any data to the view at this point. 
  @Override
  public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
      return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_todo, parent, false);
  }

  // The bindView method is used to bind all data to a given view
  // such as setting the text on a TextView. 
  @Override
  public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
      // Find fields to populate in inflated template
      TextView tvBody = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvBody);
      TextView tvPriority = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPriority);
      // Extract properties from cursor
      String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
      int priority = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("priority"));
      // Populate fields with extracted properties
      tvBody.setText(body);
      tvPriority.setText(String.valueOf(priority));
  }
}
```

Извлечение курсора

```
// TodoDatabaseHandler is a SQLiteOpenHelper class connecting to SQLite
TodoDatabaseHandler handler = new TodoDatabaseHandler(this);
// Get access to the underlying writeable database
SQLiteDatabase db = handler.getWritableDatabase();
// Query for items from the database and get a cursor back
Cursor todoCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM todo_items", null);
```

Подключение адаптера к ListView

```
// Find ListView to populate
ListView lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
// Setup cursor adapter using cursor from last step
TodoCursorAdapter todoAdapter = new TodoCursorAdapter(this, todoCursor);
// Attach cursor adapter to the ListView 
lvItems.setAdapter(todoAdapter);
```

Пусковой механизм `CursorAdapter`

```
  // Переключение на новый курсор и обновления содержимого ListView 
todoAdapter . changeCursor (newCursor);
```